# Symfony2 persist error on save

Tags: symfony

I'm having a problem with symfony2 when i'm trying to save the data from a form to my database with Doctrine.

Here is the error

```
array
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

When I expand the debug, the error seems to be on the **$em->persist($user);**

And here is my function:

```
 public function saveAction() {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PostType());

    if ($request->getMethod() == "POST") {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {

           // $user = new PostEntity();
            $user = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $this->user = $user;
     } else {
            return new Response('Erro dados invalido');
        }

    }else {
        return new Response('Erro post');
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I could fix that?

**Edit**

Here is my PostType class

```
<?php

namespace blog\PostBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('date')
    ;
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'blog_postbundle_posttype';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the PostType class?

Are you using debug page? (/app_dev.php).

---

Edit

just add this:

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'blog\PostBundle\Entity\Post',
    );
}
```

Comment: This is pr PostType class
`<?php

namespace blog\PostBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('date')
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'blog_postbundle_posttype';
    }
}`

Comment: You need to set the Entity on your Type. Check on the answer. I added over there.